# read and write binary files in python

Tags: python, binary

I have a `binary` file called "`input.bin`".
I am practicing how to work with such files (read them, change the content and write into a new binary file).
the contents of input file:

```
03 fa 55 12 20 66 67 50 e8 ab
```

which is in `hexadecimal` notation.

I want to  make a output file which is simply the input file with the value of each byte incremented by one.

here is the expected output:

```
04 fb 56 13 21 67 68 51 e9 ac
```

which also will be in `hexadecimal` notation.
I am trying to do that in python3 using the following command:

```
with open("input.bin", "rb") as binary_file:
    data = binary_file.read()
    for item in data:
        item2 = item+1
    with open("output.bin", "wb") as binary_file2:
        binary_file2.write(item2)
```

but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: What is it returning?

Comment: With current indentations you execute `write` only once - after `for` loop - so it can write only one value. Open both files in one `with` at start, and put `write` inside `for` loop.

Comment: Also, you're using `item-1` when your explanation and expected output both suggest you mean `item+1`

Comment: Please do not [deface the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55960049/revisions) because it makes the existing comments and answer/s non-understandable. You can instead put [your explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55960049/4) as a comment or as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You want to open the output file before the loop, and call `write` *in* the loop.

```
with open("input.bin", "rb") as binary_file:
    data = binary_file.read()

with open("output.bin", "wb") as binary_file2:
    binary_file2.write(bytes(item - 1 for item in data))
```

Comment: `bytes` is, I think, a little asymmetrical; it's easy to get an `int` from a `bytes`, but less easy to turn a single `int` back into a `bytes` object.

Comment: The update shows a relatively efficient way to process multiple bytes; the `struct` module is another option.